# Multiple Hyperlinks to Multiple Files

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, hyperlink, userscripts

I have an Excel spreadsheet that lists all of my stock (equity) sales and purchases in a FIFO type scenario for tax purposes, and it would make it really easy if I could hyperlink the official trade confirmation file to the corresponding cell in the spreadsheet.

Example:

- Column C:1 through C:100 are the date that list the purchases
- Column A:1 through A:100 are the stock ticker symbols
- Column G:1 through G:100 are the dates that list the sell

I need to match the ticker symbol and date to the corresponding trade confirmation that is located in `D:\tradeconfirmationsfor2016\aphqf\APHQF09072016` and link it to the date in column "C:x" and then do it again for column "G". this will link the corresponding confirmation with each entry on the spreadsheet.

[image: this an image of the spreadsheet]

In the screenshot above you can see where I have hyperlinked some of them manually but I need a faster way.

I tried to include as much information as possible, let me know if you need any additional details. I am not sure if it is a script or a macro, or what would help speed up this task because I have another similar project as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need two additional columns for your links for my solution since the formula can't reference itself.

Assuming the following A Column is the ticket symbol, Column C is the opening date the folder name is a lower case version of ticker and the file name always is the same format.

Try something like this for the opening date hyperlink:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("D:/tradeconfirmationsfor2016","/",LOWER(A1),"/",UPPER(A1),TEXT(C1,"ddmmyyyy")),[TEXT(C1,"dd/mm/yyyy")])
```